# Unable to View log files in JFrog Logs folder

Tags: artifactory

I am working om JFrog .i have installed Jfrog into my ubuntu system however i am able to startit but i am getting an error

```
{
"errors" : [ {
"status" : 500,
"message" : "Artifactory failed to initialize: check Artifactory logs 
for errors."
} ]
}
```

When i try to check my logs folder there are no files related to logs except Catalina folder.
But in JFrog documentation it has given that there will be logs related files in Logs folder [Artifactoy-logs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Log+Files)
Can someone help me with that?

Thank you

Comment: Some issues at startup time may end up written only in `catalina.out` so you should check there

Answer (score 0):

In some scenarios, when the Artifactory application is not yet ready, the logs file will not get created. When this happens, the reason for the startup failure will mostly be logged in the Artifactory's tomcat `localhost.log` file, and sometimes in the `catalina` log file. Both log files exists under the `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/tomcat/logs/` directory.